# running Python 3.9.12 on Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pycharm

I have Python 3.9.12 installed on my linux machine at the moment, and it is working fine when I launch a terminal and run a python file.  However when I try to do the same in Pycharm, the code does not work properly because the Interpreter is still 3.9.9.  Any ideas how I can upgrade the interpreter?  I tried to install Conda which has version 3.10, however I cannot seem to  be able to attach this interpreter to run my code.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: In pycharm you can select the interpreter you want, or create a new virtual environment and use the version you want. Just edit the interpreter and select the version you need

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I already tried to do that, but I cannot get the 3.9.12 interpreter, I cannot select it since its not available.  I would like to know how to make it available

Answer (score 0):

In order to navigate to your options quickly, use CTRL+SHIFT+A, which yields a search bar. When typing in `python interpreter` it will navigate you to the interpreter settings of PyCharm. When clicking on the settings cog of the defined interpreter, you can select `Add...`. Select that and you can configure your new interpreter. Please note that you must know where the executable is of the interpreter. If you are unsure, you can use:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: I tried what you said however the Interpreter is 3.9.  My question is why is my "main" terminal python version 3.9.12 whilst the one in Pycharm is 3.9.9?  I have some code that runs perfectly in the "Main" terminal window but not in PyCharm

Comment: Hi @JMon, I dont understand. The interpreter is what ever you want it to be. If you have imported a project of sorts, you might also have imported a virtual env, or some other environment parameters that PyCharm will automatically use to run your project. What your main Python version is in the terminal depends in linux on how your terminal is initialiased. Could you please share what you get back from running `sys.executable`. You might be running on the default installation of python of your OS, or might be running Anaconda..

Comment: that command returns my folder that I am working in + venv/bin/python

Comment: I am trying to run a matplotlib example, and when I run it from my terminal in linux, with python main.py it works and displays the chart.  When I try to run it in PyCharm, I get an error that module tkinter is not installed.  That is why I am suspecting that 3.9.12 is able to run this code whilst 3.9.9 cannot

Comment: Hi @JMon, so you have created a virtual environment (PyCharm prompts you to create one by default when creating a project and configures this environment as default for the project). To answer your question, your terminal uses the default environment of your operating system. This is not equal to your project specific virutal environment. If you want to use the default environment of the your operating system, please use the instructions. Please note that different environments can have different libraries installed.

Comment: Just to be clear, whether tkinter is installed, has nothing to do with what version of python you are using, but whether it has been installed in the environment that you are using. Maybe this article can help you understand the complexity of environements better https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-virtual-environments-explained-with-examples/#:~:text=virtualenv%20is%20a%20tool%20used,with%20pip%20%3A%20pip%20install%20virtualenv

Comment: what I cannot understand (since I am quite new to this) is why my terminal is using a different version of Python than PyCharm.  or better, how can i install tkinter in PyCharm env?

Comment: "If you want to use the default environment of the your operating system, please use the instructions." Which instructions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246834/discussion-between-pieter-geelen-and-jmon).